# How to pass char array and access it's value in C

Tags: c, arrays, printf

I am a begginer at C and I want to understand how to pass a char array to a method. And in the method access the array's values.
I tried making an example but i keep getting errors :/

here's my example:

```
int checkCommandSyntax(char * text);  

int main(int vcount, char* varr[])
{
    char * text = "fg something";

    checkCommandSyntax(text);


    getchar();
}  


int checkCommandSyntax(char * text)
{
    int i = 0;

    while (!(text[i] == '\0'))
    {
        printf("%s", text[i]);
        i++;
    }

}
```

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Comment: `"%s"` --> `"%c"`

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: C has functions, not "methods".  And technically, you cannot pass arrays to functions.  When you specify an array as a function argument, what gets passed is a pointer to the first element of that array.  You can access every array element via that pointer.

Comment: I suppose the errors you "keep getting" must not be important at all, otherwise you would have told us what they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine besides one simple error. You are passing printf the argument %s which means it should print a string. You are trying to print one character, so change

```
printf("%s", text[i]);
```

to

```
printf("%c", text[i]);
```

%c denotes that you want to print a character value.